# Overlay geom_histogram onto geom_smooth, so that histogram of predictor variable is on the x-axis?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to mimic the output of Figure 4.6 in Medical Risk Prediction Models: With Ties to Machine Learning, located [here](https://books.google.com/books?id=fQsVEAAAQBAJ&pg=PT86&lpg=PT86&dq=%22Medical+Risk+Prediction+Models%22+AND+%22Figure+4.6%22&source=bl&ots=0D5sPn84fo&sig=ACfU3U2iA_IEKpxJAmMt279KZ1Z2lY8TEQ&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjn8N_1qqP2AhUVlGoFHfOXC2QQ6AF6BAgEEAM#v=onepage&q=%22Medical%20Risk%20Prediction%20Models%22%20AND%20%22Figure%204.6%22&f=false)

*Plot of predicted risk overlayed with histogram of predictor variable*
[image]

The figure is a plot of the predicted risk of ovarian hyperstimulation syndrome (OHSS) by age. The data set, ivf, is located [here](https://github.com/tagteam/MedicalRiskPredictionModels/raw/master/data/ivf.rda)

I am unable to overlay a histogram of age on the x-axis of the smooth plot of the logistic regression, using R.

```
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(ivf) + 
geom_smooth(aes(x=age, y=ohss), method=glm, method.args= list(family="binomial"))

ggplot(ivf) + 
geom_smooth(aes(x=age, y=ohss), method=glm, method.args= list(family="binomial")) + 
geom_histogram(aes(x=age), inherit.aes=FALSE, fill="white", colour="gray50", binwidth=5)`
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps this?

```r
ggplot(ivf) + 
  geom_smooth(aes(age, ohss), method = glm, 
              method.args = list(family = "binomial"), color = "black") +
  geom_histogram(aes(x=age, y = ..density.. * 1.5), 
                 fill="white", colour="gray50", binwidth = 20/9) +
  scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::percent,
                     name = "Probability of OHSS") +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = seq(20, 40, 5)) +
  theme_classic()
```

[image]

Comment: This looks great! And thank you for the post edits. I didn't think to use "..density.." for the histogram, and I didn't realize ggplot has the option to vary the scale by multiplying by a factor (e.g., "* 1.5").